# Anisotropic Surface Shows Polygon Edges

Tags: uv

This is my first time using Blender, and I'm using it to modify troublesome piece of clothing by adding new polygons, welding polygon vertices etc.

Due to the new polygons, I created a new UV map by adding some seams and unwrapping using smart UV project.  I then imported the obj into Daz Studio and noticed that when I increase the anisotropy, polygon edges become visible.  When the anisotropy is 0, The polygon edges blend in as expected.

Any hints at what might be causing this?  I plan to render in Blender as well to see if the results are the same, but I am still learning.

Update #1: When I highlight some of the faces, I can see that they are no where near one another on the UV map.  Could this explain the weird results when an anisotropic effect is calculated?  See last image.  I'm not sure how to fix it though.

Update #2: A person from a different forum believes that Smart UV ignores seams.  So I tried a normal unwrap, and the resulting UV map looks a lot closer to what I was anticipating.  I'll do more work with the seams and see if that gets me to the finish line.

**Update #3: After using the regular "unwrap", as opposed to Smart UV, the mesh unwrapped in a predictable way per the seams I had added.  With the new UV Map, I no longer have issues with anisotropy.**

[image: With anisotropy set to 0%]

[image: With anisotropy set to 100%]

[image: Unwrapped UV Map]

[image: Highlighted faces]

Comment: I think Blender defaults to a radial tangent for base anisotropic direction.. have you tried explicitly plugging a _Tangent_ (UV Map) node into the 'Tangent' input of the BSDF and feeding it a UV map which matches the original, good version?

Comment: What does BSDF stand for?

Comment: I meant the _Principled_ (BSDF) shader. ((Bidirectional Scattering Distribution Function  ..  8D  .. )) Just slang. My apologies,

Comment: I'm new to all of this, so I there's still a lot of terms I don't recognize.